# Setting a static body width a good idea?

Tags: css, width

I was wondering if you could put a width on the body tag?

For example:

```
body {
background: url(bg.png);
width: 1200px;
}
```

Is that bad css, could it cause problems? I would just like to know for future reference

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely best to use a div inside the body. It is far more flexible, and makes way more sense.

See the below example, you can achieve the same thing you are trying to do with divs.

```
<body>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100%">
<div style="background: url(bg.png); width: 1200px;">
Does the same thing as the other thing, but is way more flexible. 
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing that will make your design instanly worthless on devices other than the one you are targeting it for.
You **cannot** assume that everybody is working on a screen with a 1200px width.

Especially now with the rise of the tablets, smartphones, imho, just don't do it.

Comment: True, but when I don't add any width when the browser is resized evrrything jumbles up on the page :/

Comment: Using width's is kind of essential, if you're worried about different devices you should be using different CSS files for different devices.

Comment: You can always have separate stylesheets for different media.

Answer (score 0):

@nicholas has pointed out a good pattern to use, put the width on a div within the body, not on the body itself.  Another reason that this is good practice (beyond responsive issues) is that some browser plugins like the Moz SEO toolbar add styles to the body tag.

If you set a fixed width on the body, it may be changed to 100%, making your fixed site into a broken fluid site.